# Disable 'delete item' from SHP list

Tags: list, delete, custom-permission-level

I need to **disable item deletion** for "users" in one list, but they need to be able to add new items.  Any suggestions?

Comment: So..did you manage to configure this to work?  If so, perhaps you could accept one of the answers please.

Answer (score 5):

I'll just expand on Allen Bai's answer - he's right.  If you are unfamiliar with how to 'create a custom permission based on Contribute' then reference this link on [Microsoft's website](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721640.aspx).

You need to create a custom group, name it '**Contribute not delete**', so that you and others will know what this group is for.  As you see in the picture below, the user group 'Contribute' has a collection of permissions - you'll notice that the Contribute group has 'Delete' as a permissions.

The best practise is to create a new group, don't change the default group!

[image: Contribute Permissions]

### Create new permission

A new permission is actually a collection of individual permissions - but the collection of permissions has a name - this name is the group name.  Anyway...go to:

Site settings>Site Permissions>Permission Levels>Add a Permission Level

[image]

What do you select and what should not be selected?  To answer this - take a look at the existing 'Contribute' group - make a note of all the individual permissions selected here.  You need to select all of the same ones **except delete** when you create your new group.

[image: Contribute Permissions]

For your own peace of mind you might like to ask a friendly user to test that they can create new items, but not delete items.

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom permission level based on Contribute that does not have the Delete Items option selected. Apply this permission level to the list for the desired users.

Answer (score 2):

Create **"ContributeNoDelete"** Permission. And Create Group with **"ContributeNoDelete"** permission.

Please see below link to create **"ContributeNoDelete"** Permission

http://blog.libinuko.com/2014/01/sharepoint-2013-how-to-create-contributor-without-delete-rights/

Please do comment if anything needed from my side.